# Coverflow with HTML5 video tag

Tags: jquery, html, video, coverflow

I'm looking for a jQuery Plugin or any non flash solution to built a coverflow like the i tunes coverflow:

[image: iTunes Coverflow]
<sub>(source: [wisestartupblog.com](https://wisestartupblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/itunes-cover-flow1.png))</sub>

In my case my elements would be mp4 videos which are included via the HTML5 video tag .

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+plugin+coverflow Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Quick Google search: http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/

But I'd slow down the scrolling, it's a bit intense. Looks great when you drag the slider.

Here's the JS:

```
(function($){

    function getPrefix( prop ){  
            var prefixes = ['Moz','Webkit','Khtml','O','ms'],  
                elem     = document.createElement('div'),  
                upper      = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.slice(1),  
                pref     = "",
                len      = 0;

            for(len = prefixes.length; len--;){  
                if((prefixes[len] + upper) in elem.style){  
                    pref = (prefixes[len]);  
                }  
            }  

            if(prop in elem.style){  
                pref = (prop);  
            }  
            return pref;
      }


    var vendorPrefix = getPrefix('transform');

    $.easing.easeOutQuint = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
    };

    $.widget("ui.coverflow", {

       options: {
            items: "> *",
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            item: 0,
            trigger: 'click',
            center: true, //If false, element's base position isn't touched in any way
            recenter: true //If false, the parent element's position doesn't get animated while items change

      },

        _create: function() {

            var self = this, o = this.options;
            this.items = $(o.items, this.element);
            this.props = o.orientation == 'vertical' ? ['height', 'Height', 'top', 'Top'] : ['width', 'Width', 'left', 'Left'];
            //For < 1.8.2: this.items['outer'+this.props[1]](1);

            this.itemSize = 0.73 * this.items.innerWidth();
            this.itemWidth = this.items.width();
            this.itemHeight = this.items.height();
            this.duration = o.duration;
            this.current = o.item; //initial item


            //Bind click events on individual items
            this.items.bind(o.trigger, function() {
                self.select(this);

            });


            //Center the actual parent's left side within it's parent

            this.element.css(this.props[2],
                (o.recenter ? -this.current * this.itemSize/2 : 0)
                + (o.center ? this.element.parent()[0]['offset'+this.props[1]]/2 - this.itemSize/2 : 0) //Center the items container
                - (o.center ? parseInt(this.element.css('padding'+this.props[3]),10) || 0 : 0) //Subtract the padding of the items container
            );

            //Jump to the first item
            this._refresh(1, 0, this.current);

        },

        select: function(item, noPropagation) {


            this.previous = this.current;
            this.current = !isNaN(parseInt(item,10)) ? parseInt(item,10) : this.items.index(item);


            //Don't animate when clicking on the same item
            if(this.previous == this.current) return false; 

            //Overwrite $.fx.step.coverflow everytime again with custom scoped values for this specific animation
            var self = this, to = Math.abs(self.previous-self.current) <=1 ? self.previous : self.current+(self.previous < self.current ? -1 : 1);
            $.fx.step.coverflow = function(fx) { self._refresh(fx.now, to, self.current); };

            // 1. Stop the previous animation
            // 2. Animate the parent's left/top property so the current item is in the center
            // 3. Use our custom coverflow animation which animates the item

            var animation = { coverflow: 1 };


            animation[this.props[2]] = (
                (this.options.recenter ? -this.current * this.itemSize/2 : 0)
                + (this.options.center ? this.element.parent()[0]['offset'+this.props[1]]/2 - this.itemSize/2 : 0) //Center the items container
                - (this.options.center ? parseInt(this.element.css('padding'+this.props[3]),10) || 0 : 0) //Subtract the padding of the items container
            );



            //Trigger the 'select' event/callback
            if(!noPropagation) this._trigger('select', null, this._uiHash());

            this.element.stop().animate(animation, {
                duration: this.options.duration,
                easing: 'easeOutQuint'
            });

        },

        _refresh: function(state,from,to) {


            var self = this, offset = null;


            this.items.each(function(i) {


                var side = (i == to && from-to < 0 ) ||  i-to > 0 ? 'left' : 'right',
                    mod = i == to ? (1-state) : ( i == from ? state : 1 ),
                    before = (i > from && i != to),
                    css = { zIndex: self.items.length + (side == "left" ? to-i : i-to) };
                    //css[($.browser.safari ? 'webkit' : ($.browser.opera ? 'O' : 'Moz'))+'Transform'] = 'matrix(1,'+(mod * (side == 'right' ? -0.2 : 0.2))+',0,1,0,0) scale('+(1+((1-mod)*0.3)) + ')'; 


                if(vendorPrefix == 'ms' || vendorPrefix == ""){

                    css["filter"] = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=1, M12=0, M21=" + (mod * (side == 'right' ? -0.2 : 0.2)) + ", M22=1";
                    css[self.props[2]] = ( (-i * (self.itemSize/2)) + (side == 'right'? -self.itemSize/2 : self.itemSize/2) * mod );

                    if(i == self.current){
                    css.width = self.itemWidth * (1+((1-mod)*0.3));
                    css.height = css.width * (self.itemHeight / self.itemWidth);
                    css.top = -((css.height - self.itemHeight) / 3);

                    css.left -= self.itemWidth/6 -50;
                    }
                    else{
                    css.width = self.itemWidth;
                    css.height = self.itemHeight;
                    css.top = 0;

                    if(side == "left"){
                    css.left -= self.itemWidth/5 -50;
                    }

                    }//end if


                }else{

                    css[vendorPrefix + 'Transform'] = 'matrix(1,'+(mod * (side == 'right' ? -0.2 : 0.2))+',0,1,0,0) scale('+(1+((1-mod)*0.3)) + ')'; 
                    css[self.props[2]] = ( (-i * (self.itemSize/2)) + (side == 'right'? -self.itemSize/2 : self.itemSize/2) * mod );

                }


                $(this).css(css);


            });

            this.element.parent().scrollTop(0);

        },

        _uiHash: function() {
            return {
                item: this.items[this.current],
                value: this.current
            };
        }

    });


})(jQuery);
```

But if you want scrolling you'll need a jQuery scroll plugin like this one: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel